# Helpful rolldown menu with edit possibility

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, forms

Is it possible to create a rolldown (dropdown) menu as part of a HTML form,
which has two functionalities?

1. It has the classical funcionality, to offer to the user a bunch of
   possibilities that are pulled out of a database.
2. It should have a possibility, to offer to the user to write some
   text that wasn't in the database and is missing in the possibilities
   offered at 1)

So, the possibilities from 1) should be only helpful for users that don't
want to write something new.

Comment: Have a look at the HTML5 <datalist> element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you, this is it. You could write it as an answer and possibly append some information (if you know it) how to do it, if somebody uses a browser without HTML5 support.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot test HTML4 equivalents to this. Web development is not my main profession and my browsers are all the latest versions (even for security reasons) and so able to render HTML5. These points can earn someone else.